# Why does Python try to import a local module from a non-working directory?

Tags: python, module

I have a folder structure like this:

- `script.py`
- folder_1

  - `script.py`
  - scripts

    - `features.py`
    - `__init__.py`
- folder_2

  - `script.py`
  - scripts

    - `features.py`
    - `__init__.py`

In the top level script.py file I have the following code which allows me to run each script in succession:

```
import os

list_filepath = ['folder_1','folder_2']

for filepath in list_filepath:
    # change wd
    os.chdir(filepath)
    # run script.py
    exec(open('script.py').read())
```

In the script.py file in folder_1, I have the following code:

```
import os

os.chdir('folder_1')

import scripts.features as feat
```

The features.py script in folder_1/scripts may contain something like this:

```
LIST_FEATURES = ['feat_1','feat_2','feat_3']
```

Running this script goes off without a hitch.

In the script.py file in folder_2, I have the following code:

```
import os

os.chdir('folder_2')

import scripts.features as feat
```

The `features.py` file in `folder_2/scripts` may contain something like this:

```
LIST_OTHER_FEATURES = ['feat_4','feat_5','feat_6']
```

However, when I try to use a feature in that module I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'scripts.features' has no attribute 'LIST_OTHER_FEATURES'
```

When I run `feat` by itself (in Spyder) it gives me this:

```
In[2]: feat
Out[2]: <module 'scripts.features' from 'folder_1\\scripts\\features.py'>
```

So it seems to be trying to use the features.py module from folder_1 when I want it to use the features.py module from folder_2.

How can I get it to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hacking around `import`, so when you `chdir` to `folder1`, and import `scripts`, it imports it as `scripts`, not `folder1.scripts`. So when you go to `folder2` and try to `import scripts`, effectively, it looks like you are re-importing the same thing. So that module is technically cached, and it's just using `folder1.scripts` which is just `scripts`. To the interpreter, you are doing this:

```py
import scripts.features
import scripts.features
```

To illustrate:

```py
import os
os.chdir('folder_1/features')

import features as f1

dir(f1)
['F1_FEATURES', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']

os.chdir('../../folder_2/features')

import features as f2

dir(f2)
# note, f2 is already seen as cached using the name f1
['F1_FEATURES', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

That module is cached already. So what you need to do is re-organize your folder structure:

- MainFolder/

  - script.py
  - folder_1/

    - __init__.py
    - features/

      - __init__.py
      - features.py
  - folder_2/

    - __init__.py
    - features/

      - __init__.py
      - features.py

Which should allow you to use import, rather than directly exec-ing a read-in file (which you shouldn't really be doing anyways)

```py
# in script.py
from folder_1.features import features as f1
from folder_2.features import features as f2

# and checking out the things loaded in
dir(f1)
['F1_FEATURES', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']

dir(f2)
['F2_FEATURES', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

### Edit: What would `folder_N/script.py` look like?

If you want some package script to import the features, it would look like this:

```py
# folder_N/script.py
from .features import features
```

Which you could then call like

```py
from folder_1 import script as s1
from folder_2 import script as s2

s1.features.F1_FEATURES
'hello'

s2.features.F2_FEATURES
'world'
```

However, this requires that `folder_N/script.py` is only imported via `from folder_N import script`. I'd recommend reading up on how import works for additional detail.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I have separate script.py files (i.e., 1 in each directory) and then import the corresponding feature.py module into each script?

Answer (score 1):

When you `import` a module/package python looks up for it in `sys.modules`, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loading.

You can:

- create `spec` from file by `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('foo', 'foo.py')`
- create `module` by `importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)`
- `spec.loader.exec_module(module)`

to avoid naming collision.